# Debug jquery loading issue in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes

I am developing a theme for Wordpress that uses Bootstrap.js and my own theme.js file in conjunction with jQuery. My understanding is Wordpress loads jQuery by default, correct? For some reason my javascript does not run and I am not quite sure why, I believe the jQuery library isn't loading correctly.

Here is what I find in the debugging console: http://imgur.com/o80hQFE , what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't load jQuery by default, it loads jQuery if it's added as a depency for other scripts in `wp_enqueue_script`. The error indicates that there are undefined variables somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress contains jquery but it does not load it for your script automatically,you have to tell it in the wp_enqueue_script function that you have a dependency for jquery in this script.

e.g:-

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true);

now wordpress will enable jquery for this script

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding.

Comment: and 1 more thing, please enqueue jquery before bootstrap as bootstrap has dependency for jquery